Invariance of curvature under change of orientation
In do Carmo's Differential Geometry, he states the following:

There is a separate stackexchange article on this same section, but I have some more specific questions:

Is what do Carmo writes as $\frac{d\beta}{d(-s)}(-s) = -\frac{d\alpha}{ds}(s)$ equivalent to $\frac{d}{d(-s)}(\beta(-s)) = -\frac{d}{ds}(\alpha(s))$?
How does this equality show that "$\alpha''(s)$ and the curvature remain invariant under a change of orientation?"


DoCarmo’s notation is a bit confusing. Set $\beta(u)=\alpha(-u)$. Then the chain rule tells us that $T_\beta(u)=\beta’(u)=-\alpha’(-u)=-T_\alpha(-u)$. Of course, when you go backwards, the unit tangent reverses. Now differentiate again:
$$\kappa_\beta(u)N_\beta(u)=-(-T_\alpha’(-u))=T_\alpha’(-u)=\kappa_\alpha(-u)N_\alpha(-u).$$
So the curvatures and principal normals of the two curves do in fact agree.
